# Visual Studio Code cannot find R client

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

I want to change my environment from Rstudio to Visual Studio Code, but get an error message when running code in VSC.

Error message:
`Cannot find R client at /usr/bin/R. Please check r.rterm setting.`

Followed the installation guide from VSC. (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/r)
I printed out the path with the command `which R`, which outputs the path `/usr/bin/R`.
When executing the path in the command line, R gets started correctly. Rstudio works completely fine.

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Changing RTrem linux configuration (search for `@ext:REditorSupport.r r.rterm` in Settings editor or change  `r.rterm.linux`  in `settings.json`) has no effect? By any chance, is it a remote or container or wsl session?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention this. In the settings I have of course specified the path in r.rterm.linux to /usr/bin/R. 
The environment session is local.